# Question on the use of ~ in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I'm trying to find all bash scripts in home and its subdirectories with "find" and to do this I typed the following in the terminal:

```
find  ~ -name '*.sh'
```

it returns the .sh files contained in the subdirectories but not the ones in home.

these instructions however work:

```
find . -name '*.sh'
```

I wonder why it doesn't work with " ~ " : any ideas?

**Edit**. As requested:

```
$ ls -ld ~
drwxr-xr-x 25 administrateur sudo 4096 janv. 28 13:52 /home/administrateur
$ ls -ld "$PWD"
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 janv. 28 11:15 /home
```

Comment: It works for me. What version of `find` do you run? What shell are you running?

Comment: thanks for your answer choroba : I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) and bash as shell

Comment: What directory are you in when you run `find . -name "*.sh"`?

Comment: it should work, the difference is just that the first one would output paths like `/home/username/foo.sh`, while the latter would output `./foo.sh`. Of course if you use the `-path` condition, and something like  '-path './*.test'`, then it would of course not work if `find` is given an absolute path. That's what the `~` does anyway, it gets expanded to the home directory path by the shell, before `find` even sees it

Comment: You could try something explicitly clear, like `touch "$HOME/se.688319.test"` and then `find ~ -name '*688319*'`. If it finds the file, your issue is elsewhere

Comment: @StephenKitt: I run find . -name "*.sh" in home

Comment: “Home”, as in, your home directory (where you go by running `cd`, the value of `$HOME`), or `/home`?

Comment: @ilkkachu : correct that's exactly what it does in terms of format. Still when I use ~ it seems to not look for .sh files in home itself: is this normal?

Comment: What do `ls -ld ~` and `ls -ld "$PWD"` output?

Comment: @Stephen Kitt to be more precise: \home

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: $ ls -ld ~
drwxr-xr-x 25 administrateur sudo 4096 janv. 28 13:52 /home/administrateur
administrateur@pc-linuxshop-48736:/home$ ls -ld "$PWD"
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 janv. 28 11:15 /home

Comment: Looks like you have created two accounts. Please use the form here to ask to merge them so you can respond to comments: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @Leyo `\home`? Are you using the Windows Subsystem for Linux or an actual Linux machine?

Comment: @Leyo, you can also [edit] your question to add details like that. It's better than using comments since the comment formatting sucks (esp. for multiline strings), and things can also get lost in between other comments.

Answer (score 2):

When you ran

```
find . -name '*.sh'
```

you were in `/home`, but `~` is your home directory, `/home/administrateur`, not `/home`.

So `find ~ ...` will only find files under `/home/administrateur`, not files under `/home` outside `/home/administrateur`.

Comment: If what was intended was to search `/home` by using `~` (possibly for the sake of portability between systems storing home directories under different paths, like macOS with its `/Users`), then one could use `~/..` or `"$HOME/.."` as the top-level search path.

Comment: @they `$HOME:h` in csh/tcsh/zsh would make for prettier output in that case (give some `/home/file.sh` output instead of `/home/administrateur/../file.sh`)